# Codility: Missing Integer - Java SE 8

Tags: java

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns the minimal positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A. For example, given:

```
A[0] = 4   
A[1] = 6   
A[2] = 2   
A[3] = 2   
A[4] = 6   
A[5] = 6
A[6] = 1
```

the function should return 4. Assume that:

in other words, A[K] = 2 for each K (0 <= K <= 50000), the given implementation works too slow, but the function would return 50,000

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

```
N is an integer within the range [1...100,000]
each element of array A is an integer the range [1..N]
```

My Answer is not yet successful! What is wrong with it? First let me state the obvious errors

- return value - I return 4 in the first result and that was successful
  but the second return is 1 that is not correct for the reason that
  the expected result is 50,000

my code, which works but the only first result is correct and second is not.

```
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
        int solution(int[] A) {
        int[] AN = Arrays.stream(A).filter(n -> n > 0).distinct().sorted().toArray();
        int N = AN.length;
        int min = 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < N) {
            min = i+1;
            if (min == N) {
                min = Math.max(min , Math.abs(i-N));
            }
            i++;
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: "the function should return 4" why not 3? 4 is in that array.

Comment: Your code cannot possibly be correct, because the only thing you have used the array for is in the line `int N = AN.length;`. The rest of your code does not use the array at all. So how can it possibly work? Before asking why your code doesn't work, you need to explain why you think it *should* work.

Comment: Sorry I am new in programming, That's why I ask here.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: In the example you gave, the missing integer is `3` and not `4`

The performance issue is probably caused by using the `distinct` and `sorted`.

I'll create an algorithm based on the sorted array, so its complexity is `O(n log n)`.

First we sort the array:

```
Arrays.sort(A);
```

Next we skip negative or zero numbers

```
while (i < A.length && A[i] <= 0)
   i++;
```

If now the array is fully parsed or the current element `A[i]` is not 1, then the solution is 1.

If it's not the case, we continue parsing the array `A`, we initiliase `missing` variable to 1 and if the current element equals the missing element we increment `i`, or if the current element is equal `missing + 1` we increment `missing` otherwise we stop, we found our missing integer.

In the end if our array is fully parsed without any mismatch between `missing variable` and `A[i]` then we increment `missing`.

The full code:

```
Arrays.sort(A);

int missing = 1;
int i = 0;
        
while (i < A.length && A[i] <= 0)
   i++;

if (i < A.length && A[i] == 1) {
   while (i < A.length) {
       if (A[i] == missing) {
           i++;
       } else if (A[i] == missing + 1) {
           missing++;
       } else {
           missing++;
           break;
       }
   }
            
   missing = i >= A.length ? missing + 1 : missing;
}

System.out.println(missing);
```